# RESTfull API with Spring Security OAuth2 and Facebook Graph token based login

Tags: spring, spring-boot, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I'm facing some issues when trying to secure some REST endpoints using oauth2 and Facebook Graph.

The scenario is simple: user performs login with facebook via iOS app, gets token and passes the token to my backend when requesting data (POST with Bearer token auth).

I have a Resource Server with the following config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableResourceServer
public class OAuthConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public RemoteTokenServices remoteTokenServices() {
        final RemoteTokenServices tokenServices = new RemoteTokenServices();
        tokenServices.setCheckTokenEndpointUrl("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token");
        tokenServices.setClientId("XXXXXXXXXX");
        tokenServices.setClientSecret("YYYYYYYYYYYYYY");
        return tokenServices;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
        resources.tokenServices(remoteTokenServices());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.requestMatchers()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/**" ).authenticated();
    }
}
```

I'm expecting at first to allow access only for users with valid token.